# Can't see Lint window in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, lint

Noob question...I've just installed Eclipse Classic 4.2.1, Java and the ADT. I've created my first project and have run Lint, which indicates a few warnings with exclamation marks in the Layout Editor window. The problem is that there is no Lint window showing, so I don't have access to the Quick Fix option. Right-clicking on each exclamation mark doesn't show any Lint-related options.
I have the Lint toolbar icon, but it only provides options for checking code and clearing  Lint warnings.
I've tried "Check for Updates", in cases I was missing a component, but no updates were found.

Any ideas re. how I can display the Lint window and get access to the Quick Fix feature?

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Lint Warnings

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still having this issue:

Eclipse wont show the Lint warnings view unless you have the window open where lint is added.

This window also holds the Console,Problems, Tasks views too.

Easiest way to get the view up is to open the 'Debug' perspective' first, then do:

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Lint Warnings

The lint warnings view will be added as a tab next to problems,tasks etc.